# Multiple character encodings inside one HTML page possible?

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I have a webpage that is set to **UTF-8**. But parts of its content (built in php) come from **iso-8859-1** files and are thus not displayed correctly.

Is it possible to set a specific encoding for a particular page element?

Comment: Define "come from". How are you fetching the external content exactly?

Comment: Well, a bunch of elements are stored in a file that php parses to load the required values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, instead of including that output directly, pass that php output through a conversion script.

PhP has a decent conversion function [mb_convert_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) that could make the task easier.

Comment: +1 this is the way to go. `mb_convert_encoding()` or `iconv()` will sort out all the troubles for you.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think this can be done. Since you already use UTF-8 inside the page, there must be something wrong while reading the content from other pages if you get unexpected results. You shouldn't experience any problems with a UTF-8 page.

Answer (score 0):

No, only a single encoding can be used on one page. You might want to encode your iso-stuff to entities that's generated by PHP.

Comment: I can't, these files are also used by an other website where everything is encoded in ISO

Answer (score 0):

You may end up using an iframe to display the other content so you can set your meta tag for the character encoding you need.

Answer (score 0):

How are you inserting the Latin-1 files into the page? If you're loading them as text and then including them as text, then I'd *hope* the relevant conversion would be performed for you. If you're just including the files without any transformation, that would indeed be an issue.

I don't know what PHP uses as its internal text format (e.g. Unicode) but if you can use that as an intermediate encoding, it should be okay.

Comment: PHP loads the content of the file (a list of items). I could use php to change encoding on the fly. But I hoped that I could just add an attribute to the div.

Comment: @tool: I don't believe so... it would be pretty odd, really. Bear in mind that the HTTP response has already specified the content type, optionally including encoding.

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is I remember reading somewhere that it was possible, but I can't find the article. O maybe I'm just mistaken...